# set rewriteEngine so that '/' can be used to link to other directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My project directory (using apache in windows) :

```
htdocs/myproject/
```

My myproject/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

My apache config :

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/myproject"
```

It works fine ...
But then I wanted to change my apache config to this (omitting the myproject) :

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/"
```

So I change my myproject/.htaccess (adding myproject to RewriteBase) to :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myproject
```

Got some problems here. 
My html file that have paths like below :

```
<script src="/assets/jsfile" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jsfile can't be found because it still look for htdocs/assets/jsfile .. 
I want the jsfile to be searched in htdocs/**sweet_house**/assets/ .. 
How to achieve this **without changing the html file** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file *in your htdocs* directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^assets(.*)$ /sweet_house/assets$1 [L]
```